# Finding $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{(4n-2)/(n+5)}$ is rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have to find $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\sqrt{\frac{4n-2}{n+5}}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$

I've expressed $\sqrt{\frac{4n-2}{n+5}}$ as $\sqrt{4 - \frac{22}{n+5}}$ and I think that there's no $n$ for it be rational.
Am I correct?

Comment: Try $$\sqrt{\frac{4n-2}{n+5}}=\frac pq\implies n=\cdots$$

Comment: You are not correct. There is a fairly small $n$ that makes the square root rational.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's one of the bigger small numbers, though

Answer (score 5):

*Hint* With $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $b\ne0$, we have that $\sqrt{\frac ab}$ is rational iff $\sqrt {ab}$ is rational. And for $m\in\mathbb Z$, we have $\sqrt m\in \mathbb Q$ iff $\sqrt m\in\mathbb N_0$.

Comment: Why is it that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$ is rational iff $\sqrt{ab}$ is rational?